# VBA Selenium - Extract infos from aria-label

Tags: html, vba, selenium, google-chrome, web

I'm working on a VBA Project and my goal is to get the text inside `aria-label`. I tried the following VBA code but with no success:

```
Set hr_ida = driver.FindElementByClass("wtdjmc YMlIz ogfYpf tPgKwe")

MsgBox hr_ida.Attribute("aria-label")
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="wtdjmc YMlIz ogfYpf tPgKwe" aria-label="Horário de partida: 19:35.">19:35</div>
```

Comment: here's HTML: <div class="wtdjmc YMlIz ogfYpf tPgKwe" aria-label="Horário de partida: 19:35.">19:35</div>

Comment: Keep in mind that those are 4 different classes in the quotes, not just 1 class that has spaces in it. Try it using only 1 of them instead of all 4, as I don't think `FindElementByClass` works like that.

Comment: Also keep in mind that classes can be used by multiple elements, so based on that alone, i would be surprised if there is an actual function called `FindElementByClass` (singular) - it most likely is `Elements` (plural) (but I am not familiar with Selenium)

Comment: Can you show more of the html/the url? Those look like dynamic values and should not be relied upon at all (xpath or css).

Answer (score 1):

I think using `xpath` is better when there are multiple classes. Try the following

```
Dim hr_ida As Selenium.WebElement

Set hr_ida = .FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='wtdjmc YMlIz ogfYpf tPgKwe']")
MsgBox hr_ida.Attribute("aria-label")
```

or using `css` like that

```
Dim hr_ida As Selenium.WebElement

Set hr_ida = .FindElementByCss(".wtdjmc.YMlIz.ogfYpf.tPgKwe")
MsgBox hr_ida.Attribute("aria-label")
```

Answer (score 0):

> Set hr_ida = driver.FindElementByClass("wtdjmc YMlIz ogfYpf tPgKwe")

Compound class names are not permitted and you cannot find the element by using these type of class names. Try below `xPaths`

```
Set hr_ida = driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='wtdjmc YMlIz ogfYpf tPgKwe']")
```

or

```
Set hr_ida = driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[contains(@aria-label,'Horário de partida:')]")
```